# ¿Cómo crear un RecyclerView con dos tipos de layouts?

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de crear un RecyclerView el cual tiene mensajes de un chat, de manera que tengo un layout para los mensajes recibidos y otro para los mensajes enviados.

El código que tengo en el adapter es el siguiente:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolderMessage> {

    private ArrayList<Message> messagesList;
    private int index = -1;

    public MessageAdapter( ArrayList<Message> messagesList){
        this.messagesList = messagesList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderMessage onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        index ++;
        //System.out.println(messagesList.get(index).getTypeMessage() + ", " + index + ", " + messagesList.size());
        if(messagesList.get(index).getTypeMessage() == 0)
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_mensaje_enviado,null,false);
            else
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_mensaje_recibido,null,false);
        return new ViewHolderMessage(view, messagesList.get(index).getTypeMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderMessage holder, int position) {
        holder.nameUser.setText(messagesList.get(position).getName());
        holder.text.setText(messagesList.get(position).getContent());
        holder.text.setText(position + " , "+ messagesList.get(position).getTypeMessage());
        holder.image.setImageResource(messagesList.get(position).getPhoto());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messagesList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolderMessage extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView nameUser;
        TextView text;
        ImageView image;

        public ViewHolderMessage(View itemView, int typeMessage) {
            super(itemView);
            if(typeMessage == 0) {
                nameUser = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameUserSend);
                text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textSent);
                image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageSent);
            } else {
                nameUser = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameUserReceive);
                text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textReceived);
                image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageReceived);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dentro de **onCreateViewHolder** accedo a la lista de mensajes al atributo **typeMessage** el cual me dice que si el mensaje es enviado o recibido y en base a esto creo la **view** con su **layout** correspondiente, el problema es que en algunos casos los mensajes que deben ir con **layout** de enviados aparecen como recibidos y viceversa.

Ya verifiqué que todos los mensajes tengan correcto su atributo **typeMessage** así que no entiendo por que algunos aparecen mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el método "getItemViewType".

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return messagesList.get(index).getTypeMessage();
}
```

Y en el "onCreateViewHolder" tienes el parámetro "viewType".

```
@Override
public ViewHolderMessage onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int layout = viewType == 0 ? R.layout.item_mensaje_enviado : R.layout.item_mensaje_recibido;
    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolderMessage(view);
}
```